# test if a text field is ReadOnly extjs 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using EXTJS, i have a field that i've marked as readonly (using this : Ext.getCmp('myCmp').setReadOnly(true);).

My need is to test if 'myCmp' is set to readOnly?

I've checked the documentation and i did'nt find any think, i'm quite sure that i'm messing some think. Any help ?

Comment: I think Ext.getCmp('myCmp').readOnly will be display the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's surprising, but you can check [readOnly flag](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Base-cfg-readOnly)
It's sets to true if the component is read only

```
Ext.getCmp('myCmp').readOnly
```